# How do I connect a raspberry pi to a hidden network with no password using a static ip address

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, static-ip-address, ssid, wpa-supplicant

I am connecting a raspberry pi to help a friend of mine. The wifi network it needs to be on is on a hidden SSID that has no passkey, and it needs to setup for a static ip address.

I can't have access to the router to make it static, and the gui applications the pi comes with can't seem to handle hidden networks.

This is suppose to be a very lightweight install, so I rather have the setup done through the /etc/network/interface and /etc/wpa-supplicant/wpa-supplicant files if possible and not use any external network manager for it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about configuring, not programming a RPi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to connect the Raspberry Pi to a Hidden Network:
http://www.techiesparks.com/2014/12/04/connect-raspberry-pi-wireless-network-openhidden/992

Command prompt command to find out WiFi Password= wpa_passphrase “RouterName” ‘password’
So for example= wpa_passphrase “Txlnt1” ‘703282231360’

So after typing in wpa_passphrase "Router" 'password', my password= psk="2862bf336b704145a702dc31af7a1bc353b0f4d3d1c2927344e2426027723054"

My "/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf" Fie:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network= 
{
    ssid="R1D"
    psk="2862bf336b704145a702dc31af7a1bc353b0f4d3d1c2927344e2426027723054"
}
```

My "/etc/network/interfaces" File:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0

iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-scan-ssid 1
    wpa-ap-scan 1
    wpa-key-mgmt WPA-PSK
    wpa-proto RSN WPA
    wpa-pairwise CCMP TKIP
    wpa-group CCMP TKIP
    wpa-ssid "R1D"
    wpa-psk 2862bf336b704145a702dc31af7a1bc353b0f4d3d1c2927344e2426027723054
```